# Row_number syntax error (Wordpress)

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I need help. I am beginner in SQL and in Wordpress.

This is my query.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS player_num,
CONCAT(name,' ',last_name) AS player_name, date_of_birth, phone, email 
FROM barbara_players 
ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

It is showing syntax error.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY id) AS player_num, CONCAT(name,' ',last_name) AS player_name, date_of_' at line 1 MySQL is in WP

I don't know why. I think I made it just like in tutorials. Yes, I am working in Wordpress. I want to show me number of rows and other mentioned columns.

Comment: Which DBMS does Wordpress use? And what is the **exact** error message?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY id) AS player_num, CONCAT(name,' ',last_name) AS player_name, date_of_' at line 1     MySQL is in WP.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support modern SQL like window functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a conditional count aggregate subquery to return a row number. Below assigns an increasing row number by last name:

```
SELECT 
     (SELECT Count(*) 
     FROM barbara_players t2 
     WHERE t1.last_name >= t2.last_name) AS player_num, 
     CONCAT(t1.name,' ', t1.last_name) AS player_name, 
     t1.date_of_birth, t1.phone, t1.email 
FROM barbara_players t1
ORDER BY t1.last_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
Count ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id).....

Here is a video as well about the OVER clause.

[Over Clause in SQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwEjkpFltjc)